# How to position Text Widget inside Row?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to position my text widget right in the middle of the screen while having another icon widget inside the same row but in the right-most part of the screen.
You can see it here:

[image]

The aim is to position the text where the red line is.

my code:

```
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                            text: widget.firstJsonParam)),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        OutlinedButton.icon(
                          //color: Colors.black,
                          onPressed: () {
                            
                            }
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit,
                              color:
                                  Colors.black),
                          label: Text('Edit'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Stack`:

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          const Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('Bobby'),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: OutlinedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.black),
              label: const Text('Edit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Row(
              children: [
                Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.0,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      OutlinedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.black),
                        label: Text('Edit'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: Center(child: Text('test'))),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    OutlinedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.black),
                      label: Text('Edit'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
```

[image]